# TextField margin top border have some empty spaces in material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Margin top border have some spaces in TextField material ui, I don't know what is the issue. I am using webpack 5, and "@mui/material": "5.9.3". Is any configuration need to add?

```
<TextField
          size="small"
          placeholder={"Hints"}
          fullWidth
          value={hint}
          sx={{ mr: 1 }}
          onChange={onHintChange}
        />
```

[image]

Comment: can you share a code sandbox for your issue ?

Comment: @MeetBhalodiya I accidentally imported ant.css. Thank you so much for reply. Now its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some other CSS, likely bootstrap, that is globally affecting styles on fieldsets (which is what MUI uses for the label on TextFields). Look through your CSS and see what is changing fieldsets, and then you can remove that or override it.

Comment: Yes ... I accidentally imported ant.css. Thank you so much

Comment: No problem, I had the exact same issue recently, so I'm glad i could help :P

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens from the use of label prop however since you didnt use any labels it can a problem in CSS styling.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).